# What are the expected values in Fisher's exact test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, count-data, fishers-exact-test

For me one of the most useful outputs from a chi-squared is the expected values. But in R, the expected values in a Fisher's exact test are not provided. What are the expected values in a Fisher's exact test? The same as expected values in chi-squared test?

Also, how do I provide my own expected values in a Fisher's exact test?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "my own expected values". There's only one relevant set of expected values under the null of independence, the grand total count times the product of the marginal proportions. This makes me concerned that perhaps you may be using the test for something it is not suitable for. So: $\,$ ... $\,$  1. Are your data counts? 2. Can you explain where these "expected values" you wish to supply Fisher's test with are coming from? How are you obtaining them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fisher-Yates-Irwin exact test itself has no need of expected counts; they're not relevant as far as performing the test goes. This would be why they aren't given -- they're not a necessary part of the test.

Given the marginal totals, the expected counts under independence are still the same thing, you can compute them easily (or even use a chi-squared test function to compute them for you). Since the Fisher-Yates-Irwin test is a test of independence, they're still the expected values of the counts for it (the test procedure just doesn't care what their values are).

Answer (score 0):

Although as @Glen_b pointed out, Fisher's exact test does not use "expected count" to make inference, it may be still interesting to explore it: as Note 3.3 in *Categorical Data Analysis* (2nd edition) pointed out:

> *For hypergeometric sampling, $\{\hat{\mu}_{ij}\}$ in tests of independence are exact (rather than *estimated*) expected values.  Specifically*,
> \begin{align*}
> E(n_{11}) = \frac{n_{1+}n_{+1}}{n} \text{ and } 
> \operatorname{Var}(n_{11}) = \frac{n_{1+}n_{+1}n_{2+}n_{+2}}{n^2(n - 1)}. \tag{1}
> \end{align*}

To understand the statement above, let's first review notations needed for discussing Fisher's exact test. The data layout is as follows:

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c | c c | c} 
 & \text{Column 1} & \text{Column 2} & \text{Total} \\ \hline
\text{Row 1} & n_{11} & n_{12} & n_{1+} \\
\text{Row 2} & n_{21} & n_{22} & n_{2+} \\ \hline
\text{Total} & n_{+1} & n_{+2} & n
\end{array} 
\end{align*}

By definition, in Fisher's exact text, all of the four marginal totals $n_{+1}, n_{+2}, n_{1+}, n_{2+}$ are fixed, and under the null hypothesis (independence), $n_{11}$ has hypergeometric distribution $HG(n, n_{1+}, n_{+1})$:
\begin{align*}
p(t) = P(n_{11} = t) = \frac{\binom{n_{1+}}{t}\binom{n - n_{1+}}{n_{+1} - t}}{\binom{n}{n_{+1}}}. 
\end{align*}
The results $(1)$ are then natural consequences of [hypergeometric moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Hypergeometric_test). In particular, $E(n_{11}) = n_{1+}n_{+1}/n =: \hat{\mu}_{11}$. As Glen_b mentioned, $\hat{\mu}_{11}$, in appearance, are actually the same for all common contingency table tests, and is still referred to as "(estimated, see the next paragraph for more discussions) expected count" (of the upper-left cell). Because row and column marginals are all fixed, $\hat{\mu}_{12}, \hat{\mu}_{21}, \hat{\mu}_{22}$ can be obtained by subtracting $\hat{\mu}_{11}$ from corresponding row/column totals.  Therefore, if you really want to compute them, you can program by yourself or utilize the outputs of other contingency table tests.

Let me add another remark for the "exact" vs. "estimated" part in the quoted paragraph, which hopefully helps clarify some frequently used concepts in contingency table inference.   In Pearson and likelihood $\chi^2$ tests, $\hat{\mu}_{ij} = n_{i+}n_{+j}/n$ is an estimate of $\mu_{ij} = E(n_{ij}) =  n\pi_{ij}$ under the null hypothesis (independence). So technically speaking, the "expected values" mentioned in your question, which are also R outputs you are used to see, should be more accurately referred to as "estimated expected values" (i.e., what you saw are $\hat{\mu}_{ij}$, which are not identical to unknown parameters $\mu_{ij}$). Interestingly, only for the hypergeometric sampling that applies to the Fisher's exact test, by virtue of the argument above, "expected values" is the proper terminology (i.e., $\hat{\mu}_{11} = \mu_{11}$) corresponding to the numerical outputs (however, as you stated, it was not displayed by the software).